# Code::Blocks 13.12 error - program has stopped working

Tags: c, error-handling, compiler-errors, codeblocks

I am using codeblocks 13.12. I have made a program for the following question:-

Evaluate the function to 0.0001% accuracy.
Sinx = x - (x^3/3!) + (x^5/5!) - .....

It gives error after I enter the value of x.
It says "AccuracyOfSinx.exe has stopped working".

```html
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define ACCURACY 0.000001
int main()
{
int n, num, mulx, fac, rem;
float x,term, sum;

printf("Enter x = ");
scanf("%f", &x);
num=1;
sum=0;
mulx=1;
for(n=1, term=1; term>ACCURACY ; n++)
{
 fac=num;
 do
  {
  num=num-1;
  fac=fac*num;                                /*Finds the factorial*/
  mulx=mulx*x;                                /*Computes x raised to num*/
  }
 while(fac>0);
 term = 1/fac;
 num=num+2;
 rem=n%2;                                     
 if(rem==0)                                   /* -ve sign is given to even position*/
  sum = sum-(mulx/fac);
 if(rem!=0)                                   /* +ve sign is given to odd position*/
  sum = sum+(mulx/fac);
 mulx = x;
}
printf("Sin(x)=%f", sum);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please go through the help text to see what and how to ask questions, here. Yours is not appropriate, you should have cooked it down to the line where the problem occurs, yourself, and also your question heading says not much more than that you have a problem. Learn how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem lies here:

```
 term = 1/fac;
```

It is a case of division by zero. I printed the value of `fac` before this statement, and it prints `0` before accuracy.exe stops working.

The main reason for `fac` going to `0` is

```
 num=num-1;
 fac=fac*num;
```

To prevent this, add an `if` condition to check the value of `num` before using it for calculating `fac`.

Comment: Exactly. The loop ensures that fac is 0 before executing this statement. Your last remark won't work though; in that case the loop will never end.

Comment: I tried    if(num=0) before calculating    fac , but it gives incorrect values now. Power function could be better in this situation.

Comment: @mihirbose: Yes, you may use power function, there may be some rounding off or calculation errors in the formulae.